# Import existing Gradle Git project into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle, import

I've installed eclipse gradle plugin from here

http://kaczanowscy.pl/tomek/2010-03/gradle-ide-integration-eclipse-plugin

Is there a simple way to import into eclipse gradle project using gui, not doing stuff

described here: http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html

?

Comment: The most important thing is to have all plugins up-to-date. The [Eclipse Buildship Plugin](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship) bundled with Eclipse 2020-02 has issues, but the updated version works fine. Caveat: One has to have `JavaSE-14` configured as Java Development kit. `14` is the Java version configured in Gradle.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Usually it is a simple as adding `apply plugin: "eclipse"` in your `build.gradle` and running

```
cd myProject/
gradle eclipse
```

and then refreshing your Eclipse project.

Occasionally you'll need to adjust `build.gradle` to generate Eclipse settings in some very specific way.

There is [gradle support for Eclipse](http://static.springsource.org/sts/docs/2.7.0.M1/reference/html/gradle/gradle-sts-tutorial.html) if you are using STS, but I'm not sure how good it is.

The only IDE I know that has decent native support for gradle is [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). It can do full import of gradle projects from GUI. There is a free Community Edition that you can try.

Comment: Take in account that the question explicitly says that don't want to use the gradle eclipse plugin, i.e. generating an Eclipse project from gradle. The second part of your reply applies.

Answer (score 31):

There is a simplest and quick way to import a Gradle project into Eclipse.
Just download the **Gradle plugin** for Eclipse from here.
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-0

And then from import select Gradle and your project would be imported. Then you have to click on **Build Model** to run it.

---

**EDIT**
Above link for **Gradle plugin** is no more valid. You can use the link as mentioned in the comment by @vikramvi

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/buildship-gradle-integration

Comment: Works like a charm, Thank you

Comment: I think this might need to be the correct answer not the arcane ones from three years ago.

Comment: Can also try [Buildship](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/buildship-gradle-integration). It's *official*.

Comment: In Eclipse Neon, Buildship comes pre-installed. You can just import a Gradle project rightaway after installing Eclipse.

Comment: Using STS. Eclipse Marketplace >> search 'buildship.' Now you can import gradle projects.

Comment: 404 - Sorry! We couldn't find it. :(

Comment: link in answer is no more valid, use https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/buildship-gradle-integration instead.

Comment: @ADTC You're right there is no need for this, Eclipse Oxygen comes by default with  Buildship installed right of the box.

Comment: Also Eclipse Oxygen and Eclipse Photon have the Gradle Buildship preinstalled

Answer (score 8):

Add the following to your build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
```

and browse to the project directory

```
gradle eclipse
```

Answer (score 5):

I have gone through this question earlier but did not found complete gui based solution.Today I got a GUI based solution provided by spring.

In short we need to do only that much:

1.Install plugin in eclipse from update site:
[site link](http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/gradle/nightly)

2.Import project as gradle and browse the .gradle file..that's it.

Complete documentation is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: the link is not available resp deprecated. Use: [https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship)

Answer (score 4):

The simpliest way is to use sts gradle integration and import project

http://static.springsource.org/sts/docs/2.7.0.M1/reference/html/gradle/gradle-sts-tutorial.html

Don't forget to click "Build Model" button.

Comment: Sts now gives a warning that's it will soon be decommsioned. Use buildship instead

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following steps:

1. Install the Buildship Gradle Integration using the Eclipse Marketplace. Simply type Buildship and click on search item. Now click on Install.
2. Click on File -> Import ▸ Existing Gradle Project.
3. Navigate to project root directory.
4. Click on a finish to load your project.

Might be it will take some time for the first time to import Gradle project. So please be patient on it.

Comment: running the search query shows 0 matches in the eclipse marketplace ;( weird

Answer (score 2):

Open eclipse and right click in the package explorer → import
Select gradle
Browse to the location where you checked out
Click “Build Model”
Select all the projects and hit finish

Answer (score 2):

Go to the GitHub page where they are maintain the official repository:
https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/blob/master/README.md

Copy the latest release link:
http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle (latest release)

Use this in Eclipse->Help->Install New Software..->Paste the link in "Work With"->press enter->select the names of the extension->click next and agree the license and follow the prompts.

After you have installed just import the project as a grade project and eclipse will take of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I use another Eclipse plugin to import existing gradle projects.

You can install the **Builship Gradle Gntegration 2.0** using the Eclipse Marketplace client.

Then you choose **FIle ▸ Import ▸ Existing Gradle Project.**

Finially, indicate your project root directory and click finish.

Answer (score 0):

As of the time of answering this, `Eclipse Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0)` has a `File --> Import --> Gradle --> Existing gradle project` menu option.You can use this option to import gradle project into Eclipse directly.

Answer (score -4):

Add the following to your build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
```

and browse to the project directory

```
gradle eclipse
```

Once done, you could import the project from eclipse as simple Java Project.

Comment: That just rephrases the accepted answer and adds no value.