# AndroidTreeView on Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, treeview

I have Java project for Android devices on Eclipse.

I would like to use [AndroidTreeView](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView) in my project, but I can't import the project as library cause it is a "gradle" project.

What can I do in order to work with this library?

I trying to find a way to get it work with Eclipse but anything I tried doesn't work.

I tried 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722773/import-existing-gradle-git-project-into-eclipse-for-example-hibernate-orm)

I have no problem to use another GUI tree view if someone know about it.

Answer (score 0):

just get the source, res and manifest by yourself to create a new libproject and use it.

You can also generate an aar by building this lib with android studio (gradle project is for android studio) and extract it with winrar or anything to get jar, manifest, res, assets and use them in a libproject of your own in eclipse