# How to import github library in eclipse

Tags: android, github, android-library

I am trying to use material designing library https://github.com/drakeet/MaterialDialog from github in my eclipse but I didnt found any jar file in this library project. So how can I use this library in my project in eclipse

Answer (score 3):

If you have a Gradle build, [as mentioned in the `README`](https://github.com/drakeet/MaterialDialog#step-1), you just add:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'me.drakeet.materialdialog:library:1.2.2'
}
```

As explained in the [blog post](http://drakeet.me/android-studio), this looks like (in Android Studio)

[image: http://drakeet.me/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/QQ%E6%88%AA%E5%9B%BE20140710124614.png]

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert this library project from gradle to eclipse. You can get many links over the web for it. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10730545/3374189).

The library project you are looking is build into android studio(Gradle). So I recommend you to use android studio instead of eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Android Studio with Gradle support by default. But if you want use Eclipse download Gradle plugin and add  this lib as dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'me.drakeet.materialdialog:library:1.2.2'
}
```