# Gradle does not show into eclipse import wizard

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, eclipse-plugin

I cannot find Gradle project type into eclipse import wizard as below:
[import wizard screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEETC.png)
Details about my eclipse version is as below:
 - BuildShip installed and Eclipse version:
[buildship plugin and eclipse version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8AyB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse doesn't has builtin support for Gradle.

You can use [Buildship Gradle Integration plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/buildship-gradle-integration)

Or use solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722773/import-existing-gradle-git-project-into-eclipse) answer.

Comment: I already installed Buildship but it doesn't help ;(
https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8AyB.png