# How to import code handled by gradle as library (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle, minecraft

I need to import this code into Eclipse as library on a project:

https://github.com/to2mbn/JMCCC

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Import existing Gradle Git project into Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722773/import-existing-gradle-git-project-into-eclipse)

Comment: No it's another thing, I don't need to simply import the gradle project. I need to add the gradle project as a library of another eclipse project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import existing Gradle Git project into Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722773/import-existing-gradle-git-project-into-eclipse)

Comment: People are voting to close this question, including one vote to "close as duplicate..." I don't think that's fair. The OP already said it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: You shouldn't, you should add it as a Maven/Gradle dependency.

Comment: Can't I do it without use Maven/Gradle?